# : API error (404): network hlfv11_hyperledger not found

Tags: hyperledger-composer

✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to execute transaction b5c260c02b4792c4ae4b85b3d4ccb4565a495da399d27917dccc1a84244e631f: error starting container: error starting container: API error (404): network hlfv11_hyperledger not found
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: failed to execute transaction b5c260c02b4792c4ae4b85b3d4ccb4565a495da399d27917dccc1a84244e631f: error starting container: error starting container: API error (404): network hlfv11_hyperledger not found

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is a Docker problem trying to start a new ChainCode container on a Docker Network bridge called "hlfv11_hyperledger" which doesn't exist.

(The word 'network' here is ambiguous in the error message :-( )

This is the same problem and hopefully the same solution [as a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52481476/hyperledger-composer-multi-host-installation).